Integral involving a simple pole and 4 branch points, pairwise in-and-out of the contour
For some time lately, I am facing difficulty in evaluating the following integral coming from a physics context:
$$I = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \frac{h-\cos k}{\sqrt{(h-\cos k)^2+\gamma^2 \sin^2 k}} dk$$
With $e^{ik} = z$ it becomes
$$I = \frac{i}{2 \pi}\oint_{|z|=1} dz \ \frac{ (z^2-2hz+1)}{z \ \sqrt{(1-\gamma^2)(z-z_1^+)(z-z_1^-)(z-z_2^+)(z-z_2^-)}}  \ \ \ \ $$
\
$$\text{with: } \ \ \ z_1^+ = \frac{h-\sqrt{h^2+\gamma^2-1}}{1-\gamma}, \ z_1^- = \frac{h+\sqrt{h^2+\gamma^2-1}}{1-\gamma}, \ z_2^+ = \frac{h+\sqrt{h^2+\gamma^2-1}}{1+\gamma}, \& \ \ z_2^- = \frac{h-\sqrt{h^2+\gamma^2-1}}{1+\gamma}$$
I have encountered such kind of integral except without the square root, and to determine which of the branch points are inside or outside the unit-circle-contour I came up with the following plots where the blue region in each plot determines the region where the magnitude of the branch points that lie on or inside the contour as  :

So that we get 4 conditions, and correspondingly the branch points inside the contour as:

$|h| \leq 1, \ \gamma>0 \implies \{ z_2^+,z_2^- \}$
$|h| \leq 1, \ \gamma<0 \implies \{ z_1^+,z_1^- \}$
$h>1 \implies \{ z_1^+,z_2^- \}$
$h<-1 \implies \{ z_1^-,z_2^+ \}$

Also when

$h^2+\gamma^2 \geq 1 \implies $ the branch points lie on the real axis, so that the branch cut for the 2 branch points inside the contour will pass through the simple pole at $z=0$
$h=0, |\gamma| < 1 \implies $ the branch points lie on the imaginary axis, so that ..[same as above]

With these conditions at hand I am unable to determine the contour and method to evaluate this integral. Any contribution from your end, either as methodical explanation or a reference to a suitable example will be highly appreciated.

The contour encircles all of the branch points and the pole at $0$.  The branch cuts can be taken as the segments joining the $4$ branch points.  Thus, all singularities are enclosed by the contour.  You may deform the contour to be a circle of radius $R>1$.  Then, evaluate the integral as $R\to \infty$.
